# New SSIS .dtsx file added in the TFS is can not be checked in

Tags: sql-server, tfs, ssis

I have added a .dtsx file on an  existing solution/project.The file is under the solution
explorer and it shows ,"New File".When try to do the check in it shows that ,No files checked in due to conflicting changes.

Is it alway like in TFS Source control,  - new files not automatically detected as pending changes?

What to do to check in this file

Comment: first checkout  .dtproj file - project files and  .sln file - solution file and make change and  try

Comment: How did you add this .dtsx file? Can you see a green "+" icon in front of the .dtsx file? Can you see this .dtsx file in Source Control Explorer? What conflicts did you get?

Comment: Also, did you use the latest version to add files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on my side (I'm using local workspace):

1. Get latest version of a project from TFS and open it in Solution Explorer.
2. Right click the solution, and add a .dtsx file. You'll see there is a green "+" in front of the file in Source Control Explorer.

[image]

3. Check Pending Changes, this file showed in Included Changes as expected:

[image]

But, if you add or remove a file outside Visual Studio, for example, in Windows Explorer, the **Detected changes** link appears in the **Excluded Changes** section. You may check that:

[image]